# Can't dismiss the rubber duck dialog if I don't have a mic

Tags: bug, april-fools, quack-overflow

I am totally psyched by the rubber duck addition to Stack Exchange!

I eagerly clicked on it but it wants a microphone. I don't have one, so I clicked "no" and it tells me to explain the problem anyways (I get it, I get it, har har). This question is not about that.

The problem is that I can't get rid of this dialog. Clicking "yes" lets me dismiss the dialog by clicking elsewhere.

I'm on an iPad.

Comment: For me, clicking "Yes" and then clicking elsewhere doesn't dismiss the dialog. The only way I've found is to refresh the page.

Comment: I can't reproduce the dismiss the dialog on "yes" behavior on my iPhone with either Chrome or Safari. I would like that to be the design for both responses, however.

Comment: @Donald are you associated with this Duck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to dismiss the speech bubble by clicking on the duck, but only after you're on the "Quack Overflow says,..." bubble. It works for me on my ipad, but YMMV.

Comment: But how do you get to the "Quack Overflow says,..." bubble if you don't have a mic?

Comment: Ah, I might have clicked differently in the two cases.

Comment: @Scott it doesn't matter, the duck is doing exactly the same. You just have to wait. :-)

Comment: How long? I've waited hours. Does it have to have focus for *n* minutes?    :-(    ⁠

Comment: OK, it works in Firefox.  In Internet Explorer, I get “Quack Overflow is listening…” but I don’t get the waveforms or anything after that. @Joe, are you responsible for this?